# Why does HttpClient throw a SocketTimeOutException when executing POST

Tags: java, post, httpclient

I have code similar to the following:

```
try {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(httpsUrl);
    setHeaders(post);

    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(request, "UTF-8");

    post.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
    String result = EntityReader.readContent(response.getEntity());
    checkAnswer(result);
    return result;

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ZapException("Error executing the http post request: "+e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

It sends the content of `request` to a server via POST using a httpclient instance that might have already been used before (it has persistent connections turned on, since we're sending quite some requests to the same server...).

This *sometimes* fails with a `SocketTimeoutException` with "Read timed out" as the message.
It's not clear to us, why it only fails at some times, when most times it doesn't. What gives?

Comment: I have a similiar problem when sending multiple requests to solr w/ tomcat 7. what are you sending the requests to? what are the details of your server since thats where the errors originate from

Comment: I think it was Jetty 6. But that was quite a while back...

Answer (score 3):

In the following, I assume you are using Apache Commons HttpClient (`org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`).

Maybe you get thrown a `SocketTimeoutException` simply because, occasionally, the host your HttpClient instance is communicating with takes too long to respond, triggering HttpClient's cancellation routine.
You can increase the connection timeout and the socket timeout with the following

```
HttpConnectionParams params = httpclient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams();
params.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
params.setSoTimeout(15000);
```

Aditionally, if you still face timeouts despite increasing the timeout limits, it is a good practice to handle the `SocketTimeoutException` gracefully - for example by retrying the connection a second and third time.

Comment: Doesnt HttpClient retry 3 times as default behavior?